# Cursor blinks in two fields (JTextField)

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, caret

Hello? anyone had a problem like: cursor blinking in more than one field at a time?
In my case the following happens: When you double click on a field JTextField, opens a JDialog, so
after closing this, the focus is directed back to the field clicked before opening the screen.

What happens is that after performing this action, two fields are flashing at the same time (usually the first field
screen, as well as the field in which efetuei double click).
This medium is random, there are cases in which it does not occur.

When debugging the inner class Handler, contained within the class DefaultCaret more specifically the actionPerformed method, realized
that: time is a field, and time is another, which are precisely the fields that are flashing (q seems obvious I know). but they are
the own inner classes of Java that are calling the method.

When passing over the field using the Tab, the cursor false, vanishes.

I'm using JDK 6

---

I returned the focus within the invokeLater(), but not solved. Now both synchronized flash

The first JComponent focusable is one of the fields that flashing improperly

I'm using my own FocusTraversalPolicy, does that may be influencing? The funny thing is that there is no treatment particularly strange about my class.

I noticed that the standard Java class, using a method within the Syncronized getFirstComponent(), but added the same control, but still is not ok

Comment: That's some strange behavior. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating a small program, the minimal necessary, that compiles, runs, and demonstrates your problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Your description is also a bit difficult to follow. Again if you don't get a decent solution soon, consider editing and enhancing your post above.

Comment: please and with Native OS, (JDK 6_xxx) and used Look and Feel, because on Windows platform not possible to simulating...,

Answer (score 5):

Actually it's Focus issue for me.

Normally when `JTextComponent` looses Focus `setCaretVisible(false)` / `setSelectionVisible(false)` is called and when Focus gained opposite thing happens.

After closing `JDialog` try to return Focus inside `invokeLater()`. Also check what's the first focusable `JComponent` in the `JDialog`'s parent.

Answer (score 0):

This situation occurs because the project I'm developing is quite large, so do not get small examples of implementation

The project has many components, Tables and Container's, which require focus through at the same time.

It turns out that Swing, put in a queue for execution, a lot of threads, and then dispatching them going, and while he did not finish running it, you can cram grabFocus() or requestFocus(), which does not cry, the first he has to finish everything and then run my request focus.

Resolved palliatively this situation, using the Swing SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...);

Thanks for the tips.